# is Reading Excel/csv file in spring batch loads entire file in to cache or loads batch wise only

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to use Spring batch to process large excel/csv file. Here i have one doubt that, whether it loads entire file into cache and reads the records in batch or it loads only the record in batchwise and then process.

Comment: It will only load as many rows as you defined the chunk size to be.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation M. Deinum

Comment: You could have checked that yourself as well by simply reading the `FlatFileItemReader` source code.

Comment: sure, will do that.